MySQL8 Docker Image - UTF-8 issues
I'm having an issue getting UTF-8 characters to work in the MySQL command line when I am running MySQL 8 in a Docker container.
When I copy and paste a UTF-8 character into Terminal, the character is deleted.
For example
mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');

becomes
mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');

I have tried three different ways to set up the Docker container, and they all have the same result. I have tried using the default encodings, the command line parameters (as per the documentation) and using a custom my.cnf file.
I can see the MySQL character_set variables change, but I cannot copy and paste UTF-8 characters into the MySQL command line. However, I can copy and paste UTF-8 characters via the MySQL command line for my local MySQL 5.7 database, and I can add UTF-8 characters to all 3 databases using the Intell-J DB Browser plugin.
Is this an issue with the Docker image setup of the MySQL command line tool?
Any ideas?

Details of the tests below:
1 No encodings specified:
% docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 9306:3306 -d mysql:8

% docker exec -it some-mysql mysql -uroot -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1             |
| character_set_connection | latin1             |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | latin1             |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3            |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');

2 Configuration without a conf file (using command line parameters to set the character-set)
% docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 9306:3306 -d mysql:8 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

% docker exec -it some-mysql mysql -uroot -proot                                                                                                                                                       
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1             |
| character_set_connection | latin1             |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | latin1             |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3            |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.18 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');

3 Using a MySQL Configuration file
 % cat /Users/me/Code/xxx/docker/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf 
[client] 
default-character-set = utf8mb4
 
[mysql] 
default-character-set = utf8mb4
 
[mysqld] 
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4

 % docker run --name some-mysql -v /Users/me/Code/xxx/docker/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 7306:3306 -d mysql:8

% docker exec -it some-mysql mysql -uroot -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci             |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci             |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci             |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');


Could you try modifying mysqld in the my.cnf file to:
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

@Sunny thanks, I have edited the my.cnf file as you suggested and still can't use UTF-8 in the MySQL command line

I'm sorry that it didn't work but I'm glad to see that you found the solution yourself. Cheers. :)

The problem was two fold:

The OS image used for the MySQL Docker containers does not have UTF-8 fonts installed
The Docker container did not have the UTF-8 locale set

I created a custom MySQL 8 image using this Dockerfile, which used a Debian install to copy sytems fonts:
# Stage 1: Use Debian to install locales and fonts
FROM debian:latest as build

# Install locales and fonts
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales fonts-dejavu-core && \
    locale-gen C.UTF-8 || true && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8

# Stage 2: Use official MySQL image as the base image
FROM mysql:8

# Set environment variables for UTF-8 locale
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

# Copy locales and fonts from the build stage
COPY --from=build /usr/share/fonts /usr/share/fonts
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/locale /usr/lib/locale
COPY --from=build /usr/bin/locale /usr/bin/locale
COPY --from=build /usr/sbin/locale-gen /usr/sbin/locale-gen
COPY --from=build /etc/locale.gen /etc/locale.gen
COPY --from=build /usr/bin/localedef /usr/bin/localedef

# Expose MySQL port
EXPOSE 3306

# Set default command
CMD ["mysqld"]

I built the custom Docker image with this command:
docker build -t custom-mysql:8 .

I created a new Docker container using this image:
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 9306:3306 -d custom-mysql:8

When I logged into the MySQL command line tool, I was finally able to copy and paste UTF-8 characters:
% docker exec -it some-mysql mysql -u root -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (name) VALUES ('');

